# Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 20

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ui-automation, appium-android

1. I run the android automation test from eclipse it throws

### Encountered internal error running command: Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 20

```
Appium Logfile: 

`[BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1519716463353
(12:57:43 GMT+0530 (IST)) [Appium] Merged W3C capabilities
{"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/sathish/S... into
desiredCapabilities object
{"app":"/Users/sathish/Sathish/CASA/Automation ... [Appium] Creating
new AndroidDriver (v1.39.0) session [Appium] Capabilities: [Appium] 
app: /Users/sathish/Sathish/CASA/Automation
Test/EndlessAisleAutomationTest/app/app-qa-debug.apk [Appium]  
appActivity: tech.ajira.endlessAisle.activities.TenantLoginActivity
[Appium]   appPackage: tech.ajira.endlessAisle [Appium]  
deviceName: Google Nexus 9 [Appium]   platformName: android
[BaseDriver]  [BaseDriver] W3C capabilities [] and MJSONWP desired
capabilities  were provided [BaseDriver] Expected W3C "capabilities"
to be a JSON Object but was provided with: [] [BaseDriver] Falling
back to MJSONWP desired capabilities [BaseDriver] Session created
with session id: e1e27d58-611a-4877-b8fc-8e7e98351be1
[AndroidDriver] Getting Java version [AndroidDriver] Shutting down
Android driver [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap
wasn't active [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command:
Error: Command 'java -version' exited with code 20
    at ChildProcess. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/teen_process/lib/teen_process.js:97:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
    at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:342:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:510:12) [HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 41 ms - 180`
     Please help me to fix this issue. Thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Appium is not able to connect to the running emulator. Try setting correct values for `deviceName` and `platformVersion` capabilities to find the connected device.

In command prompt try running `adb devices` to get the device name.

Comment: I check the `deviceName` and `platformVersion`. It have the correct values. I run the same code with WebDriver it's working, For AndroidDriver<MobileElement> it shown above error

Comment: Can you please post the `deviceName` that you are getting from `adb devices`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I fixed that. The problem was i set wrong JAVA_HOME env variable